# Outputting image values from files

Tags: image

I want to do some image processing. I would need to do computations on the intensity values of the image. I am unsure what free software would be able to get the job accomplished. Anyone knows whether this can be done with gimp?

Comment: i suggest using Matlab language

Comment: How do you do it in Matlab?

Comment: You can build standalone apps with Matlab: http://uk.mathworks.com/products/compiler/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using OpenCV, here:

http://opencv.org/

You can find a sample about simple image processing here:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html#basic-threshold

Tutorials index here:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/table_of_content_imgproc/table_of_content_imgproc.html#table-of-content-imgproc

Comment: OpenCV is suitable for visual recongnition